# Why are Summer Asian Games mostly held in Autumns?

Tags: asian-games

From 1986 that Summer and Winter Asian Games have been separated from each other the Summer Games were mostly held in autumns. The only Summer Games which was held completely in summer was the 2018 Games in Jakarta. The current Summer Asian Games (2022) is also mostly being held in autumn.

Is there a reason for Summer Asian Games being mostly held in autumns?

Comment: For the same reason that the 2022 World Cup was held in December, I suspect.

Comment: @PhilipKendall 2022 FIFA World Cup was held in December because its host was Qatar. This country is very hot in summers. But not all Asian countries have hot summers. Asian Games have been held in various countries since 1986.

Comment: 2006 Asian Games also was held in Doha, Qatar; and it was again held in December.

Comment: If needing to move the Asian Games to autumns because of the heat/humidity would happen often, then makes sense just to normally hold them in the autumn regularly.

Comment: @pboss3010 Jakarta is a very humid city. But yet the 2018 Summer Asian Games was held entirely in summer.

Comment: Also, if this is the reason for Asian Games, why is the 2022 FIFA World Cup the *only* World Cup that was held in outside of summer? Why isn't it regularly done in World Cups? (Of course the reason for the World Cup that was held in autumn was heat)

Comment: Even the World Cups that were held in Southern Hemisphere were held in Northern Hemisphere summer (Southern Hemisphere winter). Why did they hold those World Cups in the cold winters of Southern Hemisphere? Couldn't they hold them in December just like the 1956 Summer Olympics? 2000 Summer Olympics also was held in both summer and autumn.